# PHP and SQL and bootstrap?

Tags: php, sql

Im working on a project at the moment and I have succesfully made a simple php web site that lists data from a sql server. Is it possible to use the data from the server and insert each row into a bootstrap 'Panel with heading' Box

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, ooureason, reg_date FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. " Reason: " . $row["ooureason"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Yes, just insert the correct html around your echo statement

Comment: Yes, you can. Just echo require params and "<br>" at end